# open a web page on button click in form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, buttonclick

I want show a web page (google) when i click on the button in form(winform)....

I have tried the below code but it does not work for me.....

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form {
    bool mHooked;
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
    }

    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
        if (mHooked) return;
        // Get the form
        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        HtmlElement form = doc.Forms["f"];
        // Get the "I'm feeling lucky" button
        HtmlElement lucky = form.All["btnI"];
        lucky.Click += lucky_Click;
        mHooked = true;
    }
    void lucky_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

I am doing winforms application using c#

would any one pls help on this.....

many thanks in advance...

Comment: 105 : you haven't provide any link in the button click

Comment: Why are you not setting the url in the click event ?

Comment: @ V4Vendetta i dont know how to i just tried above one ...

Comment: why r u giving down vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Add a button to your form and in the Click event handler do this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
   //remove this from the constructor else it will be loaded along with the form
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form

{

    bool mHooked;

    public Form1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
        //webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com"); 
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com"); 
    }
    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (mHooked) return;   
        // Get the form 
        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document; 
        HtmlElement form = doc.Forms["f"];    
        // Get the "I'm feeling lucky" button 
        HtmlElement lucky = form.All["btnI"];
        lucky.Click += button1_Click;   
        mHooked = true;   
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Click of button add:

```
ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://mysite.com/");  
Process.Start(sInfo);
```

(or)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.StartProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://mysite.com/");
Process.Start(sInfo);
```

If you want to use web scraping technique to extract data from the particular website or open the website in your winform itself then use web browser control and try anyone of the answers provided by ShaliniPavan or V4Vendetta.

Comment: At least take a look at the code supplied, he has a webbrowser control. And he tries to navigate that to the desired website.